# ScrollView : Infinity scrolling with squares background

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I need to make my `ScrollView` infinity scrolling with squares background. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR34J.png) in unreal engine. I will agree if there is  a library can do that for me.
[another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywJLT.png)

Comment: `ScrollView` does not support infinite scrolling, regardless of background. You will need to investigate other solutions. Depending on your circumstances, there are ways to get a `RecyclerView` to appear infinite, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare I kow. That why i ask this question. I need ways to do it.

Comment: Did you post the wrong image? I don't know Unreal Engine but that seems to be about launching a player character at a target? Or are you talking about the tiled background?

Comment: @cactustictacs iam talking about the squares behind the blueprints. Whe you place items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `BitmapDrawable` that tiles (repeats) like this:

[image: A tileable grid image]

*tileable.png*

(That's *24px x 24px*, or *24dp x 24dp* at the base LDPI)

```
tiled.xml (in drawables)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/tileable"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:antialias="false"
    android:filter="false"
    />
```

(it's vertical and horizontal lines so we don't want any smoothing/filtering when it's scaled up for higher DPIs)

Then you can use that as a `background` in a `View` and it'll tile. If you want a `View` you can scroll infinitely for some reason, you can do it with a `RecyclerView`:

```
item_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tiled" />
```

(Height is a multiple of the *24dp* size of the tiled image so it repeats properly)

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
        ItemViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false).run(::ViewHolder)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) { }

    // not literally infinite scrolling but they'll have to work to crash it
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = Int.MAX_VALUE

    inner class ViewHolder(binding: ItemViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

Stick that adapter in a `RecyclerView` and you have a scrolling grid

```
recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter()
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
```

[image: A RecyclerView looking like a big scrolling grid]

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but there you go! If you're trying to create a scrollable field containing things you can interact with (like the node editor example you posted) that's a *whole* other thing, where the "infiniteness" is more about the widget's representation of space and its contents, and painting a tiled background that moves as you navigate that component's internal space would be the simplest part of that system.

Comment: yes i need something like node editor. Is this possible ?.

Comment: but i dont need to go depper just the layout that you put the items in it, without colors or any one of these infiniteness items.

Comment: @mariamfawaz you're talking about the user (?) being able to add `View`s to a virtual layout and that's a pretty complicated thing - if I were you I'd look for "node editor" libraries but I'm not sure if you'll find anything you can just drop into an app. Maybe some kind of wireframing library would work if you can find one of those. What you're talking about is pretty advanced and complex UI! And I don't know anything offhand that would do it for you, sorry

Comment: Thank you, I will work hard and look everywhere. I will find a solution.